# Should I add comments for the correct solution on an off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7058181/476716) is closed, but still appears highly in search results and does not have a good answer. Should we be doing anything about it, as Tobias suggests, or let an on-topic community deal with it?

Comment: I would not. The question was closed for a reason, and the only thing wrong I see is that *I can see it at all*.

Comment: The question does not belong on SO, so there's no point cleaning up the answers. I've cast my vote to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no - adding answers as comments is problematic for numerous reasons, not the least of which is that many readers may not even see them.

In situations like this, you're much better off flagging the question and asking that it be removed so that it doesn't clog search results with an unhelpful answer. Then make sure the *right* answer appears on [the *right* site.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)